# How to detect if someone is wrote something discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to check whether someone typed a message in any channel in my discord and then if it detects that the bot did type something I want it to say something, any idea on how to check if someone typed something?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the discord docs I found this:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Just replace `token` with your bots token. The rest should be self-explanatory.

Edit:

To detect a specific role you can do something like this:

```
if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            if premium_subscriber_role:
                        await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)
```

This will check if the user has the server booster role and if the user does then the bot will reply with "Hello! @username".

Comment: Say I want to check if a specific person typed anything, any way I can do that?

Comment: Thank you and im very sorry to ask again do you know if there is a way to check any message no matter what it starts with because it says that it will only check if its starts wtih !hello

Comment: You can try this: ```message.content(''):```